# Spacing of new environment in lists

Tags: spacing, lists, parskip

The title is not that descriptive. I try to write a custom `remark`-style `amsthm` environment which can take arguments as the header (I don't need referencing functionalities). I wanted to simplify the code by avoiding `trivlist`. `remark`-style theorem environments have `.5\topsep` space before and after the environment. But this looks really weird in list environments like `itemize`. Here is what I have:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for testing

% paragraph environment, takes one mandatory header text
\newenvironment{para}[1]{
    % add space before environment
    \par\addvspace{.5\topsep}
    % header text 
    \noindent\textit{#1.}%
    % default rubber space after header text and ignore following spaces
    \hspace*{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}\ignorespaces
}{
    % add space after environment
    \par\addvspace{.5\topsep}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{para}{Looks good}
    \lipsum[66]
\end{para}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[66]

        Compare \verb|\parsep| above and the \verb|\parsep+.5\topsep| below.

        \begin{para}{Looks weird}
            \lipsum[66]
        \end{para}

        \lipsum[66]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, in list environments, the `.5\topsep` is added to the non-zero `\parsep`, creating a bigger gap. The original `amsthm` environments avoid this by employing Latex' mechanisms for lists (setting `\@topsep` and `\@topsepadd` to the desired spacing of `.5\topsep`). Similarly, I would much rather prefer to add no space at all if `para` is called inside list environments. *Is there a way to detect whether one is in a list environment? Or is there a more elegant solution?*

---

**Edit:** Added picture of compiled file.

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You might be write with the convetion of `\parsep` and `\topsep`, but, first of all, I don't use `\parsep` or `\parskip` in my definition of `para`. Moreover, `latexdef -c article topsep` gives me `8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt`, and `amsthm.sty` also uses `\topsep` it it's definition. For clarification, I added a picture.

Comment: sorry I misread you using `\parsep` but the same is true of `\topsep` you should not use it here. `amsthm` uses it but amsthm theorem envionments are (like standard theorem environments) a one-item list so you can use list parameters to style them, Using `\topsep` as here out of a list is wrong. article (actualy size10.clo) does not set topsep globally it sets it separately for each list nest level, the value you show is part of `\@listi` for first level lists

Comment: For the specific question of testing for whether you are in a list or not: check the value of `\@listdepth`; 0 is outside of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [David Carlisle said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/706003/spacing-of-new-environment-in-lists#comment1755169_706003), you shouldn't use `\topsep` to define your environment, since it is set and reset by list environments and your environment will not give a consistent behavior (since it depends on a length that is frequently changed on the fly). You probably want to hard code a value (make it a glue if you want, but I'll just take `4pt` as that seems to be the desired amount).

To handle the effect of `\parskip` which may or may not be present (in a list environment, `\parskip` is set to be equal to `\parsep`), you can just cancel it by adding an additional vspace. The following will probably do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for testing

% paragraph environment, takes one mandatory header text
\newenvironment{para}[1]{
    % add space before environment
    \par\addvspace{4pt}\addvspace{-\parskip}
    % header text 
    \noindent\textit{#1.}%
    % default rubber space after header text and ignore following spaces
    \hspace*{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}\ignorespaces
}{
    % add space after environment
    \par\addvspace{4pt}\addvspace{-\parskip}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{para}{Looks good}
    \lipsum[66]
\end{para}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[66]

        Compare \verb|\parsep| above and the \verb|\parsep+.5\topsep| below.

        \begin{para}{Looks weird}
            \lipsum[66]
        \end{para}

        \lipsum[66]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]